# Auto Proxy Settings

Tags: proxy

My Android device is a *Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100* running **Android 5.1.1** on **CM12.1**. I have an issue regarding WiFi and proxy settings.

When I try to connect to my school's WiFi, I am able to connect to the router (I can ping the router), but whenever I try to load a web page, nothing loads.

I can re-produce the problem on my iPod, but I can solve it by changing the proxy settings on it from Off to Auto. Is there any way I can make my Android device do the same thing? I have already tried *Settings › WiFi* (picking the AP's entry, long-tapping it, selecting to "edit", and configure "Proxy" in the *Advanced Settings* there), but I'm not sure what the URL is for the PAC file.

My device is **rooted**. Any suggestions are very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: ah okay, but iOS allows users to select Auto for the proxy settings. In Android there is no such option?

Comment: I've never needed a proxy with my Android device, so I cannot tell, sorry.